# debugging okhttp-eventsource connection logs

Tags: java, apache-kafka, okhttp

I am writing a toy project to receive wikimedia events and stream it to kafka. I use `okhttp-eventsource` to connect to wikimedia. But I am receiving any data. I am having a hard time debug the problem.

Here is my code. The server runs fine, but I don't see events from wikimedia.

```
 public void sendMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        String topic = "wikimedia_recent";
        BackgroundEventHandler backgroundEventHandler = new WikimediaChangesHandler(kafkaTemplate, topic);
        String url = "https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange";
        BackgroundEventSource.Builder builder = new BackgroundEventSource.Builder(backgroundEventHandler, new EventSource.Builder(URI.create(url)));
        try (BackgroundEventSource source = builder.build()) {
            source.start();
            System.out.println("source started");

        }
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
    }
```

here is my handler method that I want to see logged:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(String s, MessageEvent messageEvent) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("event data -> %s", messageEvent.getData()));
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, messageEvent.getData());
    }
```

Below is my log, but I don't receive the event data from wikimedia. Any suggestion how do I go about debugging?

```
2024-02-25T12:31:56.676-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : >> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
2024-02-25T12:31:56.678-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : >> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
2024-02-25T12:31:56.679-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : >> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
2024-02-25T12:31:56.680-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10005 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org
2024-02-25T12:31:56.681-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10005 starting              : OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org
2024-02-25T12:31:56.681-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:56.681-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:56.681-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [ ConnectionPool] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 run again after   1 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:56.682-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 finished run in 428 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:56.693-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [-stream[null]-1] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : >> 0x00000003    75 HEADERS       END_STREAM|END_HEADERS
2024-02-25T12:31:56.743-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000000    12 SETTINGS      
2024-02-25T12:31:56.745-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10002 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org applyAndAckSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.745-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10002 starting              : OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org applyAndAckSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.746-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [yAndAckSettings] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10004 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org onSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.746-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [yAndAckSettings] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : >> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2024-02-25T12:31:56.746-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10004 starting              : OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org onSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.747-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10002 finished run in   1 ms: OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org applyAndAckSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.747-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10004 finished run in 165 µs: OkHttp stream.wikimedia.org onSettings
2024-02-25T12:31:56.791-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
2024-02-25T12:31:56.946-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003   797 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
2024-02-25T12:31:56.947-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003     5 DATA          
2024-02-25T12:31:57.682-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:57.682-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [ ConnectionPool] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 run again after   1 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:57.682-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10001 finished run in 397 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2024-02-25T12:31:57.972-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003    15 DATA          
2024-02-25T12:31:57.973-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003   154 DATA          
2024-02-25T12:31:57.974-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003  1287 DATA          
2024-02-25T12:31:57.974-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2             : << 0x00000003    15 DATA          
2024-02-25T12:31:57.975-05:00 DEBUG 3654 --- [m.wikimedia.org] okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);` inside the `try` block:

```
public void sendMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    String topic = "wikimedia_recent";
    BackgroundEventHandler backgroundEventHandler = new WikimediaChangesHandler(kafkaTemplate, topic);
    String url = "https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange";
    BackgroundEventSource.Builder builder = new BackgroundEventSource.Builder(backgroundEventHandler, new EventSource.Builder(URI.create(url)));
    try (BackgroundEventSource source = builder.build()) {
        source.start();
        System.out.println("source started");
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
    }
}
```